# Не устанавливается numpy в Termux

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, termux

Для решения этой проблемы я пытался обновить python до последней версии, установил python – всё это не помогло.
Вот ошибка при установке:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [264 lines of output]
      Running from numpy source directory.
      setup.py:86: DeprecationWarning:

        `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
        of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
        Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
        It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
        For more details, see:
          https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html


        import numpy.distutils.command.sdist
      Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
      Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
      Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
      Cythonizing sources
      INFO: blas_opt_info:
      INFO: blas_armpl_info:
      INFO: customize UnixCCompiler
      INFO:   libraries armpl_lp64_mp not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: blas_mkl_info:
      INFO:   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: blis_info:
      INFO:   libraries blis not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: openblas_info:
      INFO:   libraries openblas not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: accelerate_info:
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      INFO:   libraries tatlas not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      INFO:   libraries satlas not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_blas_threads_info:
      INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_blas_info:
      INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-in_33ce1/numpy_0f099b10f1da470aaf27cc166de91608/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:2077: UserWarning:
          Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
          Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
          A better performance should be easily gained by switching
          Blas library.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      INFO: blas_info:
      INFO:   libraries blas not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-in_33ce1/numpy_0f099b10f1da470aaf27cc166de91608/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:2077: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
          the BLAS environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      INFO: blas_src_info:
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-in_33ce1/numpy_0f099b10f1da470aaf27cc166de91608/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:2077: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
          the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
      INFO: lapack_opt_info:
      INFO: lapack_armpl_info:
      INFO:   libraries armpl_lp64_mp not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: lapack_mkl_info:
      INFO:   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: openblas_lapack_info:
      INFO:   libraries openblas not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: openblas_clapack_info:
      INFO:   libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: flame_info:
      INFO:   libraries flame not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      INFO:   libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_3_10_info:
      INFO:   libraries satlas,satlas not found in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_threads_info:
      INFO: Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      INFO:   libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: atlas_info:
      INFO:   libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib
      INFO: <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: lapack_info:
      INFO:   libraries lapack not found in ['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib']
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-in_33ce1/numpy_0f099b10f1da470aaf27cc166de91608/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1902: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      INFO: lapack_src_info:
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-in_33ce1/numpy_0f099b10f1da470aaf27cc166de91608/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1902: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      INFO:   NOT AVAILABLE
      INFO:
      INFO: numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
      INFO:   FOUND:
      INFO:     language = c
      INFO:     define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]
      INFO:
      Warning: attempted relative import with no known parent package
      /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-zjojectm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running config_cc
      INFO: unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      INFO: unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      INFO: build_src
      INFO: building py_modules sources
      creating build
      creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.10
      creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.10/numpy
      creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.10/numpy/distutils
      INFO: building library "npymath" sources
      WARN: Could not locate executable armflang
      WARN: Could not locate executable gfortran
      WARN: Could not locate executable f95
      WARN: Could not locate executable ifort
      WARN: Could not locate executable ifc
      WARN: Could not locate executable lf95
      WARN: Could not locate executable pgfortran
      WARN: Could not locate executable nvfortran
      WARN: Could not locate executable f90
      WARN: Could not locate executable f77
      WARN: Could not locate executable fort
      WARN: Could not locate executable efort
      WARN: Could not locate executable efc
      WARN: Could not locate executable g77
      WARN: Could not locate executable g95
      WARN: Could not locate executable pathf95
      WARN: Could not locate executable nagfor
      WARN: Could not locate executable frt
      WARN: don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
      creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.10/numpy/core
      creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.10/numpy/core/src
      creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath
      INFO: conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h
      INFO:   adding 'build/src.linux-aarch64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath' to include_dirs.
      INFO: conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c
      INFO: conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c
      INFO: None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-aarch64-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h']
      INFO: building library "npyrandom" sources
      INFO: building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_tests" sources
      creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray
      INFO: conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.c
      INFO: building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_umath" sources
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-zjojectm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 230, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-zjojectm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-zjojectm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-zjojectm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 493, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "setup.py", line 485, in setup_package
          setup(**metadata)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-in_33ce1/numpy_0f099b10f1da470aaf27cc166de91608/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
          return old_setup(**new_attr)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-zjojectm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-zjojectm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-zjojectm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-zjojectm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-zjojectm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-zjojectm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-zjojectm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-in_33ce1/numpy_0f099b10f1da470aaf27cc166de91608/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 62, in run
          old_build.run(self)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-zjojectm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-zjojectm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-zjojectm/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-in_33ce1/numpy_0f099b10f1da470aaf27cc166de91608/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 144, in run
          self.build_sources()
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-in_33ce1/numpy_0f099b10f1da470aaf27cc166de91608/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 161, in build_sources
          self.build_extension_sources(ext)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-in_33ce1/numpy_0f099b10f1da470aaf27cc166de91608/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 318, in build_extension_sources
          sources = self.generate_sources(sources, ext)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-in_33ce1/numpy_0f099b10f1da470aaf27cc166de91608/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
          source = func(extension, build_dir)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-in_33ce1/numpy_0f099b10f1da470aaf27cc166de91608/numpy/core/setup.py", line 513, in generate_config_h
          check_math_capabilities(config_cmd, ext, moredefs, mathlibs)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-in_33ce1/numpy_0f099b10f1da470aaf27cc166de91608/numpy/core/setup.py", line 176, in check_math_capabilities
          raise SystemError("One of the required function to build numpy is not"
      SystemError: One of the required function to build numpy is not available (the list is ['sin', 'cos', 'tan', 'sinh', 'cosh', 'tanh', 'fabs', 'floor', 'ceil', 'sqrt', 'log10', 'log', 'exp', 'asin', 'acos', 'atan', 'fmod', 'modf', 'frexp', 'ldexp']).
      [end of output]
```

По ссылке в тексте ошибки уже переходил, там не оказалось ничего полезного в моей ситуации.
Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

```
export MATHLIB="m"
pip install numpy
```